# Trouble using pictures in Iframe

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I'm having some trouble with using an iframe. So basically I  was trying to create a slideshow, with one of the slides being an embedded video, so I did this by using an iframe. Well, the slideshow functions properly, and the video is resized properly, but when the image slides come up, they aren't being enlarged to the size of the iframe like the video is, and they seem to have a padding of 2 or 3px around the top/left sides. I've attached the HTML and CSS code, and took some pictures to illustrate what I'm trying to say and if anyone see's the problem, I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks so much!

[image: Correct Size]
[image: Incorrect position]

**CSS CODE**

```
#imageDiv {
border: 5px solid black;
width:500px;
}
#slideshowImg {
width:500px;
height:300px;
margin:0px;
border-spacing:20px;
}
#mediaMenu table {
font-size:14px;
border:0;
margin-top:5px;
border-spacing:0;
}
table {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-spacing:0
}
#mediaMenu td {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:120px;
height:20px;
color:#CBE8E8;
}
.subMenu img {
width:100%;
height:100px;
}
.subTitle {
font-family:chalkboard, sans-serif;
background-color:#000;
font-size:12px;

}
.subTitle a {
color:#CBE8E8;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> ******* </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
slideshowImages = new Array(5);
slideshowImages[0] = new Image();
slideshowImages[0].src = 'images/tebowFinal.jpg';
slideshowImages[1] = new Image();
slideshowImages[1].src = 'images/nash.jpg';
slideshowImages[2] = new Image();
slideshowImages[2].src = 'images/kobe.jpg';
slideshowImages[3] = new Image();
slideshowImages[3].src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/9UlmwcEIWUw';
slideshowImages[4] = new Image();
slideshowImages[4].src = 'images/tbrown.jpg';
index=0;
function slideShow(source)
{
document.getElementById('slideshowImg').src = slideshowImages[source].src;
clearInterval(newPic);
index=source;
imageChange();
if (source=="3")
        {
            onclick=clearInterval(newPic);
        }
}
function slideshowForward() 
{
// increase the value of index by one or reset the value to 0 if all the slides have been cycled
index++;    
if(index >= 5) 
{
    index=0;
}
// set the image name to the slide show image
document.getElementById('slideshowImg').src = slideshowImages[index].src;
}
function imageChange() {
    newPic=setInterval(function(){slideshowForward() },5000);
}

</script>
<link href="slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload="imageChange()">

<div id="imageDiv">
<table id="mediaMenu">
    <tr>
        <td id="imageRow" colspan="5" >
            <a href="#" onclick="clearInterval(newPic)">
            <iframe id="slideshowImg"  src="images/tebowFinalFinal.jpg" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="slideShow(0)">
            <table> 
                <tr> <td class="subTitle"> Tebow Talks </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/tebow.jpg" alt="Tim Tebow"></img></td></tr> 
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="slideShow(1)">
            <table>
                <tr> <td class="subTitle">Nash attack </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/nash.jpg" alt="Steve Nash"></img></td></tr>
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="slideShow(2)">
            <table>
                <tr> <td class="subTitle">Kobe Who? </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/kobe.jpg" alt="Kobe Bryant"></img></td></tr>
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="slideShow(3)">
            <table>
                <tr> <td class="subTitle">Not So Giant </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/giants.jpg" alt="San Francisco Giants"></img></td></tr>
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="slideShow(4)">
            <table>
                <tr> <td class="subTitle">Expensive mistake </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/tbrown.jpg" alt="Terrell Brown"></img></td></tr>
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>                 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```